# ASP.NET CORE passing an ID to controller to show page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to show my data in pages using `DbContext` .

This is my Controller :

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
    {
        int _page;
        if (page.HasValue)
        {
            _page = page.Value;
        }
        else
            _page = 1;
        return View(await _context.Agent.Skip(_page-1).Take(10).ToListAsync());
```

And my layout page that contain the link :

```
 <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Agents" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="1" >סוכן</a></li>
```

Two things:

A) It doesn't seems to work, no matter what I pass in `asp-route-id` the same list is beeing shown . What am I doing wrong ?

B) After it will work, how do I present the pages for the user to choose ? (E.G. 1,2,3..90)

Thanks.

Comment: looks like you are using `asp.net core`. tag accordingly

Comment: @Rahul Yup, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michal answered you first question. Concerning you second question you could use third-party tag helpers like [pioneer-pagination](https://github.com/PioneerCode/pioneer-pagination)

Or write you own implementation of pagination logic for view like below(mostly based on [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page)), not perfect one implementation of pagination, but still working:

Model for page:

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public int PageNumber { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }

    public PageViewModel(int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => (PageNumber > 1);

    public bool HasNextPage => (PageNumber < TotalPages);
}
```

Code for tag helper:

```
public class PagerTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;
    public PagerTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
    {
        urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
    }
    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
    public PageViewModel PageModel { get; set; }
    public string PageAction { get; set; }
    public string PageController { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
        output.TagName = "div";

        // we put our links in list
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("ul");
        tag.AddCssClass("pagination");

        //show link for 1st page
        if (PageModel.PageNumber>2)
        {
              TagBuilder fstItem = CreateTag(1, urlHelper);
              tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(fstItem);
        }


        // create 3 links to current, next and previous page.
        TagBuilder currentItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber, urlHelper);

        // link to previous page if NOT 1st page
        if (PageModel.HasPreviousPage)
        {
            TagBuilder prevItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber - 1, urlHelper);
            tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(prevItem);
        }

        tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(currentItem);
        // link to next page, if NOT last page
        if (PageModel.HasNextPage)
        {
            TagBuilder nextItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber + 1, urlHelper);
            tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(nextItem);
        }


        //show code for last page
        if (PageModel.TotalPages > 4 && PageModel.PageNumber!=PageModel.TotalPages-1 && PageModel.HasNextPage)
        {
            TagBuilder lstItem = CreateTag(PageModel.TotalPages, urlHelper);
            tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(lstItem);
        }

        output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);
    }

    TagBuilder CreateTag(int pageNumber, IUrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        TagBuilder item = new TagBuilder("li");
        TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
        if (pageNumber == this.PageModel.PageNumber)
        {
            item.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
            link.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction, PageController, new { page = pageNumber });
        }
        link.InnerHtml.Append(pageNumber.ToString());
        item.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(link);
        return item;
    }
}
```

And use it in View like (**don't forget to import tag-helper in _ViewImports.cshtml**):

`<pager page-model="@Model.PageViewModel" page-action="Index" page-controller="Home"></pager>`

And code for controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page=1)
{
    int pageSize = 10;
    var count = await _context.Agent.CountAsync();
    var items = await _context.Agent.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

    PageViewModel pageVm= new PageViewModel(count, page, pageSize);
    IndexViewModel vm= new IndexViewModel
    {
        PageViewModel = pageVm,
        Agents =items // need to create table in view from Agent properties
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

And code for the IndexViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    public PageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
If you want display all PageLinks in your view you can just use for loop in Tag Helper `Process` method like below:

```
 public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
 {
     IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
     output.TagName = "div";

     // we put our links in list
     TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("ul");
     tag.AddCssClass("pagination");

     for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
     {
         TagBuilder linkItem = CreateTag(i, urlHelper);
         tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(linkItem);
     }

     output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);
 }
```

**Update 2**:

In order to use this approach don't forget to change the model for your index page to `IndexViewModel` and register tag helper in _ViewImports.cshtml. My working view (simplified) looks like this.

```
@* Using and tag helper imported in _ViewImports.cshtml *@
@model IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        @foreach (var a in Model.Agents)
        {
            <tr><td>@a.Name</td><td>@a.Age</td></tr>
        }
    </table>

</div>

<pager page-model="@Model.PageViewModel" page-action="Index" page-controller="Home"></pager>
```

**Update 3**:

1. If you use `IndexViewModel` like I wrote above, but don't use foreach like in my example, you should change `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)` to `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Agents.Name)`
2. `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` imports only built-in ASP.NET Core tag helpers. In order to import custom tags you should use `@addTagHelper *, YourAssemblyName` where `YourAssemblyName` is the name of you project ('AgentApp` for example), see [A minimal Tag Helper section in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: @sagi No problems. Glad to help.

Comment: Hey, I didn't understand where exactly to implement the use in the view `<pager ...`

Comment: I tried to put it in the `index` page, but I'm getting an error `IENumerable<Agent> doesn't contain a definition for PageViewModel`

Comment: @sagi Please check **Update2** from my answer. I think you forgot to change `@model` of your view from `IENumerable<Agent>` to `IndexViewModel`

Comment: Never mind, fixed that stupid issue, though I have another problem , I'm using this ` @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)` to display the headlines, but not the model.`Name` is underlined

Comment: And one more thing, the routing works, but only if I manually write the page number on the path. I don't see any buttons or something for previous\next page . And thanks again man . (Maybe I didn't put the taghelper in the viewImports correctly? , I used `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` )

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and guidance, almost everything worked except the `model.Agents.Name` since its IENumerable, so I used `firstOrDefault()` function instead .

Answer (score 6):

Your parameter is named `page` but you provide an `id` route value. Rename the `page` parameter in action method to `id` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. On the other subject, how do I add dynamic page selection in the bottom (generated from the amount of data exists?)